# ARM6 or ARM6 VFP?

Tags: huawei-u8150

I wanted to know if my Huawei IDEOS u8150 is ARMv6 or ARMv6 [VFP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture#VFP). One thing I know is that it is ARMv6 but is it VFP? Any good ways to find out? Huawei documentation/site/forums doesn't say anything about this. I need to know because in the Android Market for video players, there are different versions for different processor types like ARM6 and ARM6 VFP versions.

Comment: Additionally, It'd be great if anyone can suggest me a working/tested good video player on my handset that plays things smoothly.

Comment: UPDATE: Someone on other forums told me that my CPU is Qualcomm MSM7201A CPU, which is just ARMv6 without VFP (FPU). So now I wanted to know the best video player app that is fastest on a huawei ideos u8150.. if anyone's got this handset and tried video apps, i'd be thankful if you could share your experiences

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Enable USB Debugging](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html#setting-up) and download the [SDK Tools](http://developer.android.com/sdk/tools-notes.html).  Then it's super easy:

```
$ adb shell cat /proc/cpuinfo
Processor       : ARMv7 Processor rev 2 (v7l)
BogoMIPS        : 162.54
Features        : swp half thumb fastmult vfp edsp thumbee neon
...
```

Note that on my device, it's `ARMv7`, and has (among other features) `vfp` support.

Comment: thanks, though it still doesn't list out what manufacturer/model it is (like Qualcomm etc), this is close to what i've wanted. :)

Answer (score 1):

Is the video player you're referring to is RockPlayer? There is an app [Know CPU for RockPlayer](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.redirectin.android.rockplayer.cpuid) that lets you check that.

Comment: I know about that app.., interestingly, that cpu tool is not compatible with my phone.. hence I cant download it

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to differentiate between various versions of ARMv6 processors, but I can recommend a good media player. Try [MoboPlayer](http://www.moboplayer.com/moboplayer_en.html) on your Huawei u8150 and see if it plays your media. They also have various codec packages for better compatibility, but again I have no idea to tell which specific type is in a given handset.

Comment: I tried MoboPlayer with both VFP and non VFP ARMv6 codecs both of them and it failed to run videos smoothly.. I get around 5 fps on a normal AVI movie (divx) I am looking for other alternatives that are easy on my ARMv6 processor

Comment: Sounds like it's using software decoding.  Have you tried forcing the hardware decoding via settings in either RockPlayer or MoboPlayer?

Comment: Yes I've tried HW decoding.. it says it doesn't support that and switches to software decoding.. :/